# Rebuild loose missing tree in Git when there are no other missing objects

Tags: git, version-control, corruption, recovery

My Git repository claims there is a corrupted object: running `git fsck --full` says that there's a corrupted loose object in the repo. Since the object is corrupted, I can't unpack it using `git cat-file -t`, but removing the file causes fsck to report only:

```
broken link from tree 93e54230ef...
            to tree 5aec4ad...
missing tree 5aec4ad...
```

I think this missing tree is the only file that is missing, or rather that there are no dangling commits/blobs, because running `git ls-tree 93e54230ef...` shows only one line: `040000 tree 5aec4ad... android`. Also, the last-modified date on the corrupted file is yesterday, and I haven't made any changes since then. Unfortunately, I've checked the clones I have of this repository, but none of them have the missing object packed or unpacked.

**How can I rebuild a missing git tree with no dangling commits or blobs?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When all that is missing in Git is a tree, the solution is simply to **use [write-tree](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-write-tree.html)**:

```
git write-tree
```

After executing that command, the Git repository should revert to its previous state.