# Git recovery: "object file is empty". How to recreate trees?

Tags: git, git-submodules, corruption, recovery

*Note: I don't have any before-corruption clone of this repository. I believe my situation is different from others described here, because I'm missing a tree, not a blob.*

What happened:

When I tried to clone a repository over LAN (via SSH), Git returned an error saying that the repository is corrupted:

```
remote: error: object file ./objects/2e/223ce259e9e33998d434acc778bc64b393d5d4 is empty
remote: fatal: loose object 2e223ce259e9e33998d434acc778bc64b393d5d4 (stored in ./objects/2e/223ce259e9e33998d434acc778bc64b393d5d4) is corrupt
error: git upload-pack: git-pack-objects died with error.
fatal: git upload-pack: aborting due to possible repository corruption on the remote side.
remote: aborting due to possible repository corruption on the remote side.
```

I've found somewhere that `git fsck` can be used for diagnosing corruption, but it didn't tell me anything new:

```
git fsck --full
error: object file ./objects/2e/223ce259e9e33998d434acc778bc64b393d5d4 is empty
fatal: loose object 2e223ce259e9e33998d434acc778bc64b393d5d4 (stored in ./objects/2e/223ce259e9e33998d434acc778bc64b393d5d4) is corrupt
```

I've tried cloning the repository locally (using `--no-hardlinks`) to see what happens, but I got exactly the same results.

Then I've stumbled upon [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11706215/how-to-fix-git-error-object-file-is-empty), and the guy who answered just deleted the empty file (step 3), so i did this (i.e. i've deleted file `223ce259e9e33998d434acc778bc64b393d5d4` from subdirectory `objects/2e/`).

`git fsck` again, and i see:

```
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
broken link from    tree 838e437f371c652fa4393d25473ce21cbf697d7a
              to    tree 2e223ce259e9e33998d434acc778bc64b393d5d4
dangling commit 54146bc0dc4eb3eede82a0405b749e05c11c5522
missing tree 2e223ce259e9e33998d434acc778bc64b393d5d4
dangling commit 864864feec207786b84158e526b2faec7799fd4e
dangling blob d3cfd7cc7718d5b76df70cf9865db01c25181bfb
```

So, there is now a problem with tree `838e437f37`.  That's not what happened to the guy mentioned above, so I went googling and found [some information from Linus](http://git.kernel.org/?p=git/git.git;a=blob;f=Documentation/howto/recover-corrupted-blob-object.txt;h=323b513ed0e0ce8b749672f589a375073a050b97;hb=HEAD#l20).

So, I did `git ls-tree 838e437f371c652fa4393d25473ce21cbf697d7a` and in the output there was a line reading:

```
040000 tree 2e223ce259e9e33998d434acc778bc64b393d5d4    moje
```

Now, "moje" is a directory (unlike the example which Linus explained, which was a file). I guess that's why next step suggested by Linus, `git hash-object moje` returned `fatal: Unable to hash moje`.

But anyway, there was just a small chance that it was what I needed, so I went looking further. I ran `git log --raw --all --full-history -- moje/` and according to Linus' guide, there should be a commit which lists 2e223 as a SHA-2 hash of some content, but there's none. And the list ends with

```
fatal: unable to read source tree (2e223ce259e9e33998d434acc778bc64b393d5d4)
```

I tried looking at the last commit listed before that error, but I didn't find this hash. I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11639751/rebuild-loose-missing-tree-in-git-when-there-are-no-other-missing-objects), but it didn't help me, probably because there *were* some changes between the problematic version and current state of working tree.

There's one thing that may be important: inside `moje/` there's a directory `cli/` which is a Git repository itself (a submodule). I've looked for the problematic SHA-2 hash there, but haven't found it.

What should I do?

Comment: Great feedback, but you could also post it as your own answer to your question. You could even accept your own answer, but don't do that ;) Chronial's answer earned his "tick mark" fair and square.

Comment: Sure, Chronial's answer will remain the accepted one :)  I've moved the solution to a separate answer as suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this command to get a list of the commits that contain your missing tree:

```
git rev-list --all | xargs -l -I '{}' sh -c 'if git ls-tree -rt {} > /dev/null 2>&1 ; then true; else git log --oneline -1 {}; git ls-tree -r -t {} | tail -1; fi'
```

Now you need to recreate the missing tree, by placing the exact same contents in there as you had in there back then and then adding that tree to the repo. The easiest way to do that is probably to just recreate the contents and then commit them to the repo (you can remove that commit afterwards).

Comment: Thanks, it worked! I found the problematic commit, looked at the differrence between its parent and the first descendant that wasn't corrupted, and i managed to recreate the tree. I'll edit my question to show the solution in detail.

Comment: Glad I could help. I think you should move the detail of your solution to a separate answer, though. (Yes, you can answer your own questions).

Comment: Update: according to Chronial's suggestion i moved the solution to [a separate answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14871420/2058424).

Answer (score 6):

The command (suggested by Chronial)

```
git rev-list --all | xargs -l -I '{}' sh -c 'if git ls-tree -rt {} > /dev/null 2>&1 ; then true; else git log --oneline -1 {}; git ls-tree -r -t {} | tail -1; fi'
```

returned the first commit that depended on missing `2e223ce` object - its SHA-2 hash was `499b8fb`. Its parent was all right (I could see its content, check it out, etc.), and I was also able to check out the next commit after the broken one (`89b0fc4`).

Now I needed to see what changes happened between these two "good" commits - that was easy: `git diff 499b8fb~ 89b0fc4` returned

```
diff --git a/somefile b/somefile
deleted file mode 100644
index f5d1e1e..0000000
--- a/somefile
+++ /dev/null
@@ -1,79 +0,0 @@
[ contents of the deleted "somefile"... ]
diff --git a/moje/cli b/moje/cli
index 640a825..c0b1a24 160000
--- a/moje/cli
+++ b/moje/cli
@@ -1 +1 @@
-Subproject commit 640a825cd671dfba83601d6271e7e027665eaca8
+Subproject commit c0b1a24aa246289831ec7db3a8596376db1f625a
```

Now I know that between the parent of the bad commit and the good commit the file `somefile` was deleted, and submodule's HEAD changed from `640a825` to `c0b1a24`. I went to the submodule repository and asked what commits happened between those two:

```
git log --oneline 640a825..c0b1a24
```

which returned

```
c0b1a24 <commit message>
8be9433 <commit message>
02564e1 <commit message>
```

Now I knew that four things happened between `499b8fb~` and `89b0fc4`:

- `somefile` was deleted
- `/moje/cli` HEAD was changed from `640a825` to `02564e1`
- `/moje/cli` HEAD was changed from `02564e1` to `8be9433`
- `/moje/cli` HEAD was changed from `8be9433` to `c0b1a24`

I didn't know which part happened in `499b8fb` (the bad commit), and which in `89b0fc4`. But fortunately there are not that many possibilities, so i just tried every one of them. With each combination I made a commit so that Git would calculate appropriate objects and store them in the database. It turned out that when `/moje/cli` HEAD was at `8be9433`, `git commit` resulted in creating the missing `2e223ce` object - hooray!

Note: if you're having a similar situation and you're poking around to see which commits are good and what Git can tell you about them, remember that being able to `checkout` a commit and `show` it are two different things. For example, I initially thought that if `git show somesha` throws an error it means that `somesha` commit is corrupted, and I cannot use it for anything. That turned out to be false: while `git show 89b0fc4` returned an error, I was able to `git checkout 89b0fc4` and also `git diff 499b8fb~ 89b0fc4` worked.

I suppose that's because `git show somesha` shows what changes are introduced by `somesha`, and for that Git needs to read the content of the previous commit (in this case a corrupted one). Apparently, Git doesn't need to look at the previous commit to check out one.

(I managed to do this thanks to [Chronial's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14831593/2058424) - kudos to him!  I was advised to post this as my own answer.)

Comment: Thanks so much for elaborating the steps you took to fix it! Helped me save the history of a corrupted repo.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but for me it does return the same error:
```
error: object file .git/objects/9c/e0546f12bffd80d73f648586a9d399b27ad201 is emp
ty
error: object file .git/objects/9c/e0546f12bffd80d73f648586a9d399b27ad201 is emp
ty
fatal: loose object 9ce0546f12bffd80d73f648586a9d399b27ad201 (stored in .git/obj
ects/9c/e0546f12bffd80d73f648586a9d399b27ad201) is corrupt
```

Comment: Which command returns the same error?  If you mean the diff between parent of the broken commit and child of the broken commit (`git diff 499b8fb~ 89b0fc4` in my case), keep in mind that the first uncorrupted commit after the bad one may be further away.
PS btw, maybe you should write a separate question.